# I keep getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, object-detection-api

Iam using jupyter notebook.
I have already installed object_detection module using:
pip install object-detection-api
But keep getting this error.
Help somebody.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What specifically did you install and how? Might not mean you are wrong, but an internet search brings no matches up. The two related ones I see on the Python Package Index don't match what you wrote exactly. Examples: [object-detection 0.0.3](https://pypi.org/project/object-detection/) & [tensorflow-object-detection-api](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-object-detection-api/). On the point about 'how'. In a cell in your notebook try `%pip install <package_name>`, see https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez.

Comment: The point about 'how' comes from the confusion that depending on how you set things up, what environment backs your notebook might not be where you installed stuff. The magic `%pip install` command I reference that you run within the notebook where you are trying to use the module **usually** helps bypass any of that confusion. I say usually because not always. That is why it comes back to the specifics. I'm trying to test if installing in a fresh environment via pip doesn't work for that package because it has dependencies pip doesn't handle on its own. However, trying your command fails.

Comment: There's a ton of details with how to install, including pre-requisites, versions, etc. Please see this page on how to install: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Please follow the instructions given in [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) link to help you to install object detection api.